# Best way to inject Serilog into repository for logging

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I can inject the ILogger into a controller but I'm having an issue trying to inject it into a repository class.
Here is my Startup method:

```
 public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Set up configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
     .MinimumLevel.Error()
     .WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(
         env.WebRootPath, "log-{Date}.txt"))
     .CreateLogger();}
```

This is in my Configure method:

```
   loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
```

My Controller:

```
 private readonly ISkillsRepo _repo;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public HistoryAndReportsController(Context db, ILogger<SkillsRepo> logger)
    {
        _repo = new SkillsRepo(db, logger);
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

The repo:

```
  private readonly Context _db;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public SkillsRepo(Context db, ILogger<SkillsRepo> logger)
    {
        _db = db;
        _logger = logger;

    }
```

I can inject the logger into the controller and then pass it to the repo but there must be a way to inject the logger into the repo directly but I can't find any examples.
I can create another logger instance in the repo but that defeats the purpose of DI. I have the same issue understanding how to do the same with the DBContext.

Comment: You can inject _SkillsRepo_ into your controller's constructor.  DI chain will automatically inject _DBContext_ and _Logger_ into the SkillsRepo. In this case, your SkillsRepo need to be register in Startup.cs

Comment: Thanks Igor. I was able to get your suggestion to work after I added the repo to the ConfigureServices in the Statup class.             services.AddScoped<ISkillsRepo, SkillsRepo>();

Comment: Igor what if you want to pass to the constructor some string value which comes from appsettings.json, how the registration would look like in the Startup class?

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been mentioned you need to register your `repository` in the dependency injection (DI) container first.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, AwesomeUserRepository>();
        ...
    }
```

`ILoggerFactory` (and therefore `ILogger<T>`) are [framework provided injections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) and don't need to be added manually.

Answer (score -1):

Igor's answer was the solution with the addition of adding your repo to the services otherwise you get an error.

"Unable to resolve service for type "

Comment: Please provide a complete full solution in your answer.